# Any chance to use nested Spacebars Tags? (here: Messageformat Package, Autocomplete)

Tags: meteor, spacebars

i wond if it's anyhow possible to solve this problem with Spacebars in Meteor:

```
{{TplVar placeholder="{{mf 'identifier' 'defaultval'}}"}}
```

This sytnax causes a syntax error.

If the placeholder would not contain spaces - as far as i know - just keeping it free of curly brackets would solve the solutions but this doesn't work here.

I'm a bit at a wall now - should there be really no way to solve it? I've already searched around for jagged handlebars/spacebars template tags but couldn't really find anything useful - especially not for the Meteor context.

Thanks in advance for helping!
Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used the Messageformat package (which looks interesting), but from [the docs](http://messageformat.meteor.com/docs#javascript) it looks like there's a javascript API.  So you can just do something like:

```
{{TplVar placeholder=thisPlaceholder}}
```

and

```
Template.yourTemplate.helpers({
    thisPlaceholder: function() {
      return mf(this.identifier, this.defaultval);
    }
});
```

Note that I'm assuming `identifier` and `defaultVal` are in the data context here - if they're the results from helper functions, you need to replicate those functions within this new *thisPlaceholder* helper and replace `this.identifier` and `this.defaultval` with the results.

Comment: Thanks, that definitely looks like a solution though i was hoping theres a syntax to get it solved without an additional helper function.

Comment: Not possible - it lists the possible arguments [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spacebars).  *"An argument to a helper can be any path or identifier, or a string, boolean, or number literal, or null."*.  So you can't include another helper, and you also can't return a function [(under *Function returning a Template*)](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/devel/packages/spacebars).

Comment: To clarify, you can't include another helper *with arguments* - supplying a single term that refers to a helper is fine.